# Will Rebuilding Indexes stop my production database to work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was using SQL Server 2012 as my production since more than 2 years. In this period, I added some indexes but never touch fragmentation. Honestly, I was unaware about index fragmentation. But Today When I ran,

```
SELECT 
    dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema', 
    dbtables.[name] as 'Table', 
    dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
                             AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE 
    indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY 
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

I got these results:

```
Schema  Table                           Index                           avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbo     ELMAH_Error                 IX_ELMAH_Error_App_Time_Seq         99.2438563327032                529
dbo     ELMAH_Error                 PK_ELMAH_Error                      98.8664987405542                794
dbo     ProductsCountriesVariants   PK__Products__3214EC270AC6A076      98                              100
dbo     Tags                        PK_Tags                             91.2820512820513                195
dbo     ProductGallery              PK_ProductGallery                   89.0909090909091                220
dbo     devicecatalog               IX_DeviceCatalog_NativeDeviceID     88.5964912280702                342
dbo     Products                    IX_Products_RetailerID_ModelNumber  88.5245901639344                122
dbo     Products                    IX_Products_RetailerID_SKU          82.7272727272727                110
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Should I rebuild all indexes? Will it effect my database running on production? The interesting thing is that I have just created `IX_DeviceCatalog_NativeDeviceID` index few minutes ago.

Comment: Is your `IX_DeviceCatalog_NativeDeviceID` an index on a `uniqueidentifier` (GUID) column?

Comment: @marc_s, no varchar(500)

Comment: @marc_s, I have some columns which have `NULL` index-name but 83% of `avg_fragmentation_in_percent`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuilding an index will lock the table unless you specify that the operation is done online:

```
ALTER INDEX REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

That is only available in Enterprise version and above.

Comment: Then what should you suggest. Should I rebuild all indexes? Why after adding an index within few minutes its fragmentation become 90%

Comment: I am using the Web version.

Comment: With web version you cannot rebuild indexes without locking tables.

Comment: It will just lock that table not the complete database?

Comment: Yes, just the table and any query that tries to access that table.

Comment: Those tables look really small though, so it shouldn't take long.

Comment: At which avg_fragmentation_in_percent should I rebuild index?

Comment: Entirely depends on your situation. If you keep on top of it, the fragmentation will be kept fairly low.

Comment: `ALTER INDEX REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)`? Will it take  table name or index name?

Answer (score 1):

You can also see if a **reorganize** will help until you can do a full rebuild. You need to do more research but basically, **reorganize** as often as needed to keep your fragmentation under 20-30% until you can **rebuild** it during off-hours. Ignore anything with less than 15-20 pages because the fragmentation is not reliable.

Indexes with a NULL name are temporary indexes the system creates until the service is restarted.